# Can't get $_Sessions to pass to another page because of using the Functions.php to create an new record in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have a form in Wordpress that creates through functions.php a record in the database.

```
<form name="order_form" method="POST" action="<?php echo esc_url( admin_url('admin-post.php') ); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

I am using Sessions to call the values from a previous page.

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php $_SESSION['last_name'] = $_POST['last_name'];?>
```

When the from is successfully submitted this is how it goes to another page.

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['success'])): 
echo "<script>window.location='https://website.com/client/upload-client/'</script>";?>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php if(isset($_GET['error'])): ?>
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <h3>Sorry! Unable to submit the form.</h3>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The problems is the variable is not been passed to the target page.
I have tried all sorts of solutions with not success.

Comment: Where is $_GET['success'] coming from?

Comment: It is coming from functions.php. If a new record was created in the database then $_GET['success']  is invoked and the user is directed to the new page. The problem as stated is the values are not being carried to the new page.

Comment: Oh, the WordPress functions.php? Since it's not in your code above, I couldn't tell how it's being referenced. I haven't touched WP in a while, but I found this article talking about using PHP sessions in WP.  https://www.ironistic.com/insights/using-php-sessions-in-wordpress